# How to find parametric equations for the line through $_0=(9,−1,1)$ perpendicular to the plane $10+12−4=10. =9+10$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

How would I find the parametric equations for the line through  $_0=(9,−1,1)$  perpendicular to the plane  $10+12−4=10.$?

Given:
$=9+10$

What is $y$ and $z$?

So first what I do is find the normal vector to the plane which is as follows:
$\left\langle10,12,-4\right\rangle$

Then I used that to find the parametrization of the line: $_0=(9,−1,1)$

and so I get $y=-1+12t$ and $z=1+-4t$.right or wrong

Comment: As per your question, you are looking to obtain parametric equation of the line which you have already done. What else are you looking for? It is not clear.

Comment: @MathLover im trying to find y and z as well. sorry I'm really stupid I got it now

Comment: Why $y$ and $z$ only, why not $x$? Are you finding $y, z$ for a particular value of $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direction vector for this line is $v=(10,12,-4)$ (i.e normal vector is $N=10i+12j-4k$) and it must pass through the point $P_{0}=(9,-1,1).$

Thus we have parametric equations $$(x,y,z)=(9,-1,1)+(10,12,-4)t=(9+10t,-1+12t,1-4t).$$

Comment: $y=-1+12t$ and $z=1-4t$ in parametric form as can be seen above. Substitute $t=0$ and what do you get?

Comment: yea my bad dude i was looking for a number this whole time I'm so stupid man someone kill me

Answer (score 1):

Your parametric equations are right, but that is not how you use them. Instead, it represents that you can obtain every point on the line for $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

For instance, substitute $t$ for $1$ and you get a point $(19,11,-3)$ which is on the line. Substitute $t$ for $0$ instead, you will get $(9,-1,1)$, which is also on the line.

As long as you substitute $t$ for the right value, you can get any point on the line. And that is the spirit behind parametric equations. You can represent the line which would have taken you three parameters with only one!

Comment: thx, but what does that mean

Comment: I edited the answer. Does it help?

Comment: idk bro im still confused. does that mean t isn't a number

Comment: You can replace $t$ with any value, and you can get any point on the line in return. Parametric equations allow you to express $x,y,z$ with only one parameter. Different values of $t$ get you different points, but they’re all on the same line which the parametric equations represent.

Comment: yea so I subbed "t" for 1 and solved for y and z but it's wrong answer

Comment: What do you mean it’s wrong?

Comment: my numbers up there, 1/12 and 1/4, the math software said it was wrong

Comment: $10x+12y-4z=10$ is the equation of the plane, not the line.

Comment: yea but how to find y and z doe

Comment: You substitute $t$ for $1$, and according to the parametric equations you have, you will get $x=19$, $y=11$, $z=-3$.

Comment: I highly recommend you go to your math teacher, which is a professional, for help. It seems like you have a serious gap in your knowledge of mathematics.

Comment: nvm, dude 11 and -3 are still not the right answers

Comment: math software still telling me its wrong

Comment: It can be either the software or the way you understand parametric equations that is wrong. I can’t spend too much time dealing with your problem. A professional math teacher can come to your rescue.

Comment: k thx anywayz take care